# Is there an option to view what percentage of questions have an accepted answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, statistics

Is there an option to view what percentage of questions in a community have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can live with data that is at maximum 7 days old you can use [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to query for that data.

I've created [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/291743/accepted-posts-and-post-count-across-database) that uses a small generating query to create a query that runs across all databases and is an union of this query:

```sql
select (select 
        count(*) 
        from [StackOverflow].dbo.posts 
        where posttypeid=1 
        and acceptedanswerid is not null), 
       (select count(*) 
        from [StackOverflow].dbo.posts 
        where posttypeid=1),  
       'StackOverflow'
```

This is the top 10 of communities with the highest percentage of accepted questions, at the date of posting:

```
site                |# Accepted          |#Questions          |Perc
Puzzling            |1476                |1855                |79,5687331536388
Spanish             |1610                |2124                |75,8003766478343
German              |3527                |4662                |75,6542256542257
Rpg                 |8409                |11406               |73,7243556023146
French              |2018                |2744                |73,5422740524781
Japanese            |4272                |5812                |73,5030970406056
Russian             |838                 |1185                |70,7172995780591
Boardgames          |3525                |5045                |69,8711595639247
Homebrew            |2408                |3563                |67,5834970530452
Outdoors            |1204                |1786                |67,4132138857783
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm finding.

Comment: [ubuntu.se] at the bottom I expect :P

Answer (score 17):

Sure, this is possible using the built in search of every site.

For example on MSE itself:

[image] [image] [image]

Gives 0.496 which is 49.6% questions with accepted answer.

Worth to warn that the "answered" percentage that can be seen in the [full list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is not related to acceptance, it means questions with at least one answer that has positive score. (88% answered for MSE for example)

Answer (score 4):

> On **[this link](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered)**, you find an overview of all sites, the amount of questions, the percentage of questions answered, and more.

[Camil Staps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/205264/camil-staps) answered this and then deleted it, however I appreciate his response.

The *percentage answered* figure is the proportion of questions that have an answer with a positive score or an accepted answer, not just the questions that have an accepted answer.