# Accepted answer rate: why is it higher on language sites?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

After seeing [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251864/245360) of [rene](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene), I was wondering why the acceptance rate top 7, has 5 language sites.

From that post:

```
site                |# Accepted          |#Questions          |Perc
Puzzling            |1476                |1855                |79,5687331536388
Spanish             |1610                |2124                |75,8003766478343
German              |3527                |4662                |75,6542256542257
Rpg                 |8409                |11406               |73,7243556023146
French              |2018                |2744                |73,5422740524781
Japanese            |4272                |5812                |73,5030970406056
Russian             |838                 |1185                |70,7172995780591
...
```

What does make users accept an answer more frequent on language sites (above 70% in the top 10), than on SO (just 56%)?

Does it have to do with the type of user? The site design? Anything else?

Can we learn something from this data?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just easier to ask (and to understand enought to ask properly) about language than tech or math :

```
What does *this* means?
```

or

```
How do you say *this* in *language*?
```

Comment: That means there should be more (upvoted) answers too. Checking...

Comment: [french.se], at least, frowns on these questions. We outright close questions for which a simple dictionary lookup would suffice. So I don't think this explanation holds much weight.

Comment: @PatrickHofman http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/195762/average-number-of-votes-on-all-sites Language sites are fairly heavy voters, but not at the very top like for accepted answers.

Comment: I'd have thought that this would apply *more* to tech and maths websites to be honest. `Q: What is 0!? A: 1`

Comment: To ask "What is 0!?" You have to : 1- find this "0" output, 2- be sure this "0" depends of the problem and is relevant, 3- give enought context for people to understand why you get this "0" ...